# How to insert a row into KDB using qPython

Tags: python, kdb, qpython

I'm trying to use a script to connect to a KDB and insert rows into a table in the KDB using qpython (https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython). My table has the following column types:
`"symbol","symbol","int","timestamp","string","string","symbol","symbol","string","string","string"`

I tried using `'.u.upd'` but this returns nothing and does not update the table:

```py
time = [numpy.timedelta64((numpy.datetime64(datetime.now()) - today), 'ms') for x in range(1)]
row = [qlist(['test'], qtype=QSYMBOL_LIST), qlist(['test'], qtype=QSYMBOL_LIST), qlist([1], qtype=QINT_LIST), qlist(time, qtype=QTIME_LIST),
        qlist([['t','e','s','t']], qtype=QSTRING_LIST), qlist([['t','e','s','t']], qtype=QSTRING_LIST), qlist(['test'], qtype=QSYMBOL_LIST), qlist(['test'], qtype=QSYMBOL_LIST),
        qlist([['t','e','s','t']], qtype=QSTRING_LIST), qlist([['t','e','s','t']], qtype=QSTRING_LIST), qlist([['t','e','s','t']], qtype=QSTRING_LIST)]

result = self.q.sendSync('.u.upd', numpy.string_('tableName'), row)
```

When I try using insert I get the error 'type:

```py
result = self.q('tableName insert (`test;`test;1i;2019.08.09D12:00:00.123123123;("t"; "e"; "s"; "t");("t"; "e"; "s"; "t");`test;`test;("t"; "e"; "s"; "t");("t"; "e"; "s"; "t");("t"; "e"; "s"; "t"))')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the tablename by reference not by value when using insert, .i.e.

`` result = self.q('`tableName insert (`test;`test;1i;2019.08.09D12:00:00.123123123;("t"; "e"; "s"; "t");("t"; "e"; "s"; "t");`test;`test;("t"; "e"; "s"; "t");("t"; "e"; "s"; "t");("t"; "e"; "s"; "t"))') ``

Note the backtick in front of the tablename.

For your other issue, `.u.upd` specifically only exists in a realtime/tickerplant setup and is not a built-in q function.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that it's only defined in vanilla kdb+tick. So not necessarily defined in all tick setups if you don't use the vanilla scripts

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! After I added the backtick to the table name, I got a 'length error and had to add a timestamp to my insert list. After that I was able to insert.